# Upgrade to Grakn core and python API 1.8.1 makes several Type methods fail - how to fix it?

Tags: python, runtime-error, vaticle-typedb

The following code worked in the python API for Grakn 1.5.9:

```
concept_type = next(iterator_conceptMap).get("x")
concepts_sub = concept_type.subs()
```

since updating Grakn and the Python API to 1.8.1, the code produces the error

> AttributeError: 'AttributeType' object has no attribute 'subs'

(and the same error for EntityTypes, RelationTypes and Roles)

The same error happens for other methods: attributes(), keys() .. (haven't tested all).

I have checked that `concept_type.is_type()` returns `True`.

Not sure if relevant, but the error occurred after substituting the `collect_concepts()` method throughout the app using the above syntax or list comprehensions, given that the method had been removed (see the [Pull Request](https://github.com/graknlabs/client-python/pull/77)).

The relevant [concept API docs](https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/concept-api/type#retrieve-all-subtypes) haven't changed.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs relevant to this question are found here:
https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/concept-api/overview

Before the Grakn clients version 1.8.0, concepts always retained a connection to the server directly. This enabled users to do calls into the Grakn server using using methods like `subs()` and `keys()`.

As of >1.8.0, client-side concepts are *either* `Local` concepts or `Remote` concepts:

- `Local` concepts are simple value objects that retain Id, Label, Type, Value (for attributes) and other state they directly contain. Clients return `Local` in general from queries and other operations.
- `Remote` concepts are obtained from `Local` concepts by passing a transaction to the concept using `concept.asRemote(tx)`. This re-enables them to connect to the server as in the older versions of the grakn clients.

This change was made to ensure users are aware which operations are potentially expensive and require trips over the network, and which are fast and operate on local values only.